# Как к цене привязать несколько валют?

Tags: php

прошу подсказки - как к цене привязать несколько валют ?
Сайт почти готов и хотелось бы что то по проще.
У меня выводит одно любое название как напишешь (доллар,рубль,евро),
а нужно что бы выводилось все три и пользователь мог выбрать одну ?
Или есть другие варианты ?

```
  введите сюда код
function field_func_31 ($d, $arr, $data)
{
    global $global_suff;
    global $rru;
    
    $data[1]=_chis($data[1], 'intval');
    if(!$data[1]) $datas=''; else $datas=$data[1];
    
    if($d=='add')
    {
    ?>
    <tr><td width="35%">
    <? if($arr['field_error']) echo '<font size=+1 color=red>*</font> '; ?>
    <font color=green><b>
    <? echo $arr['field_form'].',евро'.$rru['cena_valuta']; if($arr['field_suff']) echo ' '.$arr['field_suff']; ?> 
    <span id="suff_a"><?=$global_suff?></span>
    </b></font>
    <td>
    <input id="<?=$arr['field_field']?>" onKeyUp="parce_chis(this.value, '<?=$arr['field_field']?>')" name="<?=$arr['field_field']?>[1]" value="<?=_font($datas, $arr['field_format'])?>" size="10">
    <input type="hidden" name="suff_b" value="<?=$arr['field_suff']?>">
    <?
    }
    
    if($d=='prov')
    {
    if (!$data[1] && $arr['field_error']) $data[0] = $arr['field_error'];
    elseif($data[1] && $arr['field_min_max_err'] && (($arr['field_min'] && $data[1]<$arr['field_min']) || ($arr['field_max'] && $data[1]>$arr['field_max'])))
    $data[0] = $arr['field_min_max_err'];
    return $data;
    }
}
```

Подскажите пожалуйста как сделать проще ?

Answer (score 0):

Необходимо найти API с курсом валют (можно брать из центр. банков, они обычно дают API курса). После чего конвертировать указанную валюту на сайте в доллары и т.д

P.S я бы вам не советовал запускать сайт с подобным кодом, если всё это самописный сайт, то уверен, что в нем будет множество дыр (исходя из кода в примере).

Comment: Да сайт самописный, да и хочу я что то по проще. Добавил в БД поле с евро , так можно и другие валюты вписать, но как выводить на экран нужную по выбору или как переключать валюты ? Мне бы такой вариант подошел, но как реализовать эту задумку ? Если знаете подскажите пожалуйста.